# How do I render JavaScript Image object from template level?

Tags: javascript, image, knockout.js

I am having an observable array of image objects, and I wonder how would I render those images from template perspective ?

**EDIT:**

What I am doint is something like this :

```
<div data-bind="html: viewBoxImageHTML()">
```

Where `viewBoxImageHTML` is a property of an object :

```
    self.viewBoxImage = ko.observable();
    self.viewBoxImageHTML = ko.computed(function(){
      if(self.viewBoxImage()){
          return self.viewBoxImage();
      }
      return '<p>LOADING IMAGE</p>';
    });
```

And this viewBoxImage is just an image that is loaded in some async loading method.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is "from a template perspective"? Knocouts template page seem fairly self explanatory http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html

Comment: @NazarGargol - I can't see anything wrong with it  but then again you didn't provide the contents of viewBoxImage or explain what is happening. Is it a html string of <img src="">? If not it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it through a custom binder like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.imageBinding = {
update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    //appends the image to the binded element
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    $(element).html(value);
}
```

};

Sample usage:

```
<div class="divWithImage"
     data-bind="imageBinding: SomeImageObject">                    
</div>
```